# Will Stripe.net 2.1.0 use TLS 1.2 if the host has SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 set?

Tags: .net, stripe-payments, tls1.2, stripe.net

We have a .Net 4.5 app using Stripe.net version 2.1.0 and Stripe will soon require connections to be made via TLS 1.2.

We don't have the source code for Stripe.net 2.1.0, but the app we are using it in has bootstrapped the security protocol like so:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

The oldest version of the Stripe.net library available for download is 2.3.0:

https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/releases/tag/v2.3.0

In this version the Stripe.net does not specify a security profile, so I can only assume priors did not as well.

It does not specify a security protocol, so is it safe to presume that my global security protocol setting will be sufficient in enforcing the specified TLS protocol types?

Comment: If Stripe.net allows you to set the API url you can attempt to perform a request against https://api-tls12.stripe.com the request will not actually process but the url will return a success / error message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is exactly how Stripe.net sets the security protocol for the .net 4.5 version of the library. With that said, your server might need some configuration as well. You can check that your TLS implementation is working properly [by submitting a charge to Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2#dotnet).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14094473)

Comment: I did provide an answer. I started my response with "Yes".